# In Flutter google maps api, when current location is changing on the map, how can I guide the driver to take left or right

Tags: flutter, google-directions-api

I have my app in Flutter and using google map in it, I'm faced to this problem;

when my driver going from source to destination my app should notify him to take left or right when arrive in some corners.

how should I do this, I call google directions api when driver click start and directions api gives me all the corner information between source and destination, here I'm confused how should implement this?

this is the information I get from directions api.

```
{
    distance:{text: 87 m, value: 87}, 
    duration: {text: 1 min, value: 23}, 
    end_location: {lat: 49.2871235, lng: -123.1170166}, 
    html_instructions: Head <b>northeast</b> on <b>Burrard St</b> toward <b>W Pender St</b>, 
    polyline:{points: _hykHpmmnVEKU_@CEc@s@k@_A}, 
    start_location: {lat: 49.2865557, lng: -123.117851}, 
    travel_mode: DRIVING
}
{
    distance: {text: 84 m, value: 84}, 
    duration: {text: 1 min, value: 21}, 
    end_location: {lat: 49.28766539999999, lng: -123.1162061}, 
    html_instructions: Continue straight to stay on <b>Burrard St</b>, 
    maneuver: straight, polyline: {points: okykHjhmnVa@q@s@mAWa@}, 
    start_location: {lat: 49.2871235, lng: -123.1170166}, 
    travel_mode: DRIVING
}
 {
    distance: {text: 1.2 km, value: 1218}, 
    duration: {text: 4 mins, value: 228}, 
    end_location: {lat: 49.2823592, lng: -123.1022275}, 
    html_instructions: Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>W Cordova St</b>, 
    maneuver: turn-right, 
    polyline: {points: }nykHhcmnVNq@BOJa@BGPq@HUDMJ_@FQBKNm@HWHS@ANWNYXc@R]h@}@BEBGBG@EJa@BE@ENUXc@BCFM~AkC`@u@hAmBt@qAR_@nAyBVc@hBaDJMDIFOFODQLg@BUTiCd@kEBIBI?EHo@Da@\cDh@uEFaAF{@@a@?c@?UBgE}, 
    start_location: {lat: 49.28766539999999, lng: -123.1162061}, travel_mode: DRIVING
}
{
    distance: {text: 0.1 km, value: 98}, 
    duration: {text: 1 min, value: 34}, 
    end_location: {lat: 49.2832417, lng: -123.1021964}, 
    html_instructions: Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Columbia St</b>, 
    maneuver: turn-left, polyline: {points: wmxkH|kjnVO?iAAgACM?}, 
    start_location: {lat: 49.2823592, lng: -123.1022275}, 
    travel_mode: DRIVING
}
{
    distance: {text: 0.1 km, value: 130}, 
    duration: {text: 1 min, value: 41}, 
    end_location: {lat: 49.2833182, lng: -123.1039742}, 
    html_instructions: Turn <b>left</b> at the 2nd cross street onto <b>Powell St</b>,
    maneuver: turn-left, 
    polyline: {points: gsxkHvkjnVErG?h@ABG^}, 
    start_location: {lat: 49.2832417, lng: -123.1021964}, 
    travel_mode: DRIVING
}
 {
    distance: {text: 31 m, value: 31}, 
    duration: {text: 1 min, value: 17}, 
    end_location: {lat: 49.2834984, lng: -123.1036901}, 
    html_instructions: Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Alexander St</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the right</div>, 
    maneuver: turn-right, 
    polyline: {points: wsxkHxvjnVGICAECCCCAAECCCW}, 
    start_location: {lat: 49.2833182, lng: -123.1039742}, 
    travel_mode: DRIVING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the current latitude and longitude with the location package and show the html instructions when the driver gets close to a turn.

Comment: I have done like so, but its not accurate as google map app is, for example google map app give a default instruction tells head south/north/west ... when I click start at the firs time, whereas I don't have the first instruction to tell my driver head south or north.

Comment: hey @Zia, did you manage it? I am also in the same boat.

Comment: Hey @AdilShinwari no I switched to external maps, I may try this in the next version of my app.